# How do I know which goals of a maven plugin are report goals?

Tags: maven

On Maven's documentation of reports, it mentions how one can use the `<reportSets>` stuff to select specific report goals. However, there's no mention on how, absent decent documentation, one can find out which goals are report goals and which are not.

Now, when using -X to debug an issue, I did notice that, absent a `<reportSets>` section, maven searches for all "report goals" provided by a plugin. Is there any way to easily access that information?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think there's a good way... Googling around, it seems Maven is reflectively looking for a method `executeReport` on the goal's MOJO. For `maven-javadoc-plugin` for example, you can find it in the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-javadoc-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/javadoc/AbstractJavadocMojo.java#L1898). But that's by looking directly at the code... If it's not properly documented for a plugin, I don't see any other way of knowing.

Comment: I couldn't find any detail either. Pity the [help:describe](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html) goal doesn't help much, not even in full details, where you may guess something but barely on names/properties/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the information which goal is report goal and which is not you can simply take a [look at the goal list](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/plugin-info.html) there is list showing which goal is a report goals which is not.

[image]

Unfortunately on command line you are right.

Comment: I assume you mean I'm right that it is not available from the command line? I fully expected it to _be_ available from the command line, and I just didn't know how!